# Elixir marshal ISO 8583 message error with Erlang library

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework, iso8583

I am new to elixir and I need to create ISO 8583 client with this language and Phoenix framework. I found an Erlang library for it from stackoverflow thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32662329/using-erlang-library-with-elixir), compiled successfully and followed the example in the repository [here](https://github.com/mgwidmann/erl8583/blob/master/src_examples/example_3_client.erl) but got error when marshaling the message. Here is my Elixir code to marshal the message:

```
msg1 = :erl8583_message.new()
msg2 = :erl8583_message.set_mti("0800", msg1)
msg3 = :erl8583_message.set(3, "300000", msg2)
msg4 = :erl8583_message.set(24, "045", msg3)
msg5 = :erl8583_message.set(41, "11111111", msg4)
msg6 = :erl8583_message.set(42, "222222222222222", msg5)
msg7 = :erl8583_message.set(63, "This is a Test Message", msg6)
marshalled = :erl8583_marshaller_ascii.marshal(msg7)
```

That's just an elixir version from the example on the repo. This is the error I've got when running the app:

```
[error] #PID<0.438.0> running TestlangIsoClientWeb.Endpoint (cowboy_protocol) terminated
Server: 127.0.0.1:4001 (http)
Request: POST /api/process
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in :erl8583_marshaller_ascii.marshal_data_element/2
        (erl8583) /home/muhammad/Workspace/testlang/testlang_iso_client/deps/erl8583/src/erl8583_marshaller_ascii.erl:168: :erl8583_marshaller_ascii.marshal_data_element({:n, :fixed, 4}, "0800")
        (erl8583) /home/muhammad/Workspace/testlang/testlang_iso_client/deps/erl8583/src/erl8583_marshaller.erl:108: :erl8583_marshaller.marshal/2
        (testlang_iso_client) lib/testlang_iso_client_web/controllers/my_controller.ex:61: TestlangIsoClientWeb.MyController.process/2
        (testlang_iso_client) lib/testlang_iso_client_web/controllers/my_controller.ex:1: TestlangIsoClientWeb.MyController.action/2
        (testlang_iso_client) lib/testlang_iso_client_web/controllers/my_controller.ex:1: TestlangIsoClientWeb.MyController.phoenix_controller_pipeline/2
        (testlang_iso_client) lib/testlang_iso_client_web/endpoint.ex:1: TestlangIsoClientWeb.Endpoint.instrument/4
        (phoenix) lib/phoenix/router.ex:278: Phoenix.Router.__call__/1
        (testlang_iso_client) lib/testlang_iso_client_web/endpoint.ex:1: TestlangIsoClientWeb.Endpoint.plug_builder_call/2
        (testlang_iso_client) lib/testlang_iso_client_web/endpoint.ex:1: TestlangIsoClientWeb.Endpoint.call/2
        (plug) lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/handler.ex:16: Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler.upgrade/4
        (cowboy) /home/muhammad/Workspace/testlang/testlang_iso_client/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_protocol.erl:442: :cowboy_protocol.execute/4
```

Is there something I missed to make it work? Any help would be very appreciated.

#### Updated

I have tried to changed the string parameter to charlist, but still got the same error. Here is the code snippet:

```
def test(conn, _params) do
  IO.puts("Test")
  msg1 = :erl8583_message.new()
  msg2 = :erl8583_message.set_mti('0800', msg1)
  msg3 = :erl8583_message.set(3, '300000', msg2)
  msg4 = :erl8583_message.set(24, '045', msg3)
  msg5 = :erl8583_message.set(41, '11111111', msg4)
  msg6 = :erl8583_message.set(42, '222222222222222', msg5)
  msg7 = :erl8583_message.set(63, 'This is a Test Message', msg6)
  marshalled = :erl8583_marshaller_ascii.marshal(msg7)
  json(conn, %{status: "ok"})
end
```

Here is the function `erl8583_marshaller.erl:108` mentioned in the stacktrace:

```
marshal(Message, MarshalHandlers) ->
    OptionsRecord = parse_options(MarshalHandlers, #marshal_options{}),
    {Marshalled1, Message1} = init_marshalling(OptionsRecord, Message),
    MarshalledMti = encode_mti(OptionsRecord, Message1),  % --- Line 108
    Marshalled2 = <<Marshalled1/binary, MarshalledMti/binary>>,
    {MarshalledBitmap, Message2} = encode_bitmap(OptionsRecord, Message1),
    Marshalled3 = <<Marshalled2/binary, MarshalledBitmap/binary>>,
    MarshalledFields = encode_fields(OptionsRecord, Message2),
    Marshalled4 = <<Marshalled3/binary, MarshalledFields/binary>>,
    end_marshalling(OptionsRecord, Message2, Marshalled4).
```

And here is the function `erl8583_marshaller_ascii.erl:168` mentioned in the stacktrace:

```
%%
%% Local Functions
%%
marshal_data_element({n, llvar, Length}, FieldValue) when length(FieldValue) =< Length ->
    erl8583_convert:integer_to_string(length(FieldValue), 2) ++ FieldValue;
```

I don't understand why the call to that function was failed to match with parameters `{:n, :fixed, 4}, "0800"` that was sent from my function. I have tried to change the double quotes to single quotes with no success. Is there any other suggestions what am I supposed to do?

Comment: Try changing double quotes to single quotes. `"foo"` in Erlang translates to `'foo'` in Elixir.

Comment: Tried that but still got the same error:

** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in :erl8583_marshaller_ascii.marshal_data_element/2
        (erl8583) /home/muhammad/Workspace/testlang/testlang_iso_client/deps/erl8583/src/erl8583_marshaller_ascii.erl:168: :erl8583_marshaller_ascii.marshal_data_element({:n, :fixed, 4}, "0800")

Answer (score 3):

there may be a bug in the code.
you can reference this issue [here](https://github.com/mgwidmann/erl8583/issues/3)

there is one elixir library out which is relatively new.

its  called [ale8583](https://hex.pm/packages/ale8583).

documentation is still coming out on this one but looks very promising.

you can check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing charlists instead of strings:

```
msg1 = :erl8583_message.new()
msg2 = :erl8583_message.set_mti('0800', msg1)
msg3 = :erl8583_message.set(3, '300000', msg2)
msg4 = :erl8583_message.set(24, '045', msg3)
msg5 = :erl8583_message.set(41, '11111111', msg4)
msg6 = :erl8583_message.set(42, '222222222222222', msg5)
msg7 = :erl8583_message.set(63, 'This is a Test Message', msg6)
marshalled = :erl8583_marshaller_ascii.marshal(msg7)
```

There is potential for confusion here:

- What Erlang calls "strings" and puts in double quotes (`"foo"`), Elixir calls "charlists" and puts in single quotes (`'foo'`).
- What Elixir calls "strings" and puts in double quotes (`"foo"`), Erlang calls "binaries" and puts in double quotes plus angle brackets (`<<"foo">>`).

It seems like the erl8583 library expects Erlang strings throughout.

Comment: Tried that but still got the same error: ** (exit) an exception was raised: ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in :erl8583_marshaller_ascii.marshal_data_element/2 (erl8583) /home/muhammad/Workspace/testlang/testlang_iso_client/deps/erl8583/src/erl8583_marshaller_ascii.erl:168: :erl8583_marshaller_ascii.marshal_data_element({:n, :fixed, 4}, "0800")

Comment: That's strange... Did you change `"0800"` to `'0800'` as well? I wouldn't expect that library to turn strings into binaries...

Comment: Yes I am sure I have changed the string to charlist as you suggest, I tried in a new project as well to make sure. Please see my updated question.

Comment: I have tried using `'0800'`, `['0', '8', '0', '0']`, `[0, 8, 0, 0]`, `<<'0', '8', '0', '0'>>` with no success. What am I doing wrong?